# why are the words not printing into the new file? java on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, methods

this is the code I have. I am printing words with only 5 letters from a document named: words.txt", I am taking those words of 5 letters, and creating a new file named: "five.txt".
but when I open the file, the words are not there. here's my code:

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {
           
             try (Scanner in = new Scanner("words.txt");
                     
                     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("five.txt");)
                 {
                     while (in.hasNext())
                         {
                     
                     String word;
                      
                        word = in.next();
                        if (word.length() == 5)
                        
                        out.println(word);
                        
                         }
                 }
         
         
             catch (IOException e)
                 {
                     
                     System.out.println("Could not read the words: " + e.getMessage());
                     return;  // Exit main now
                 }
         
         
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `new Scanner("words.txt")`

That doesn't do what you think it does. That will make a scanner for the input 'words.txt'. Not, 'the contents of the file "words.txt"'. No, literally, 'words.txt'. Which has one token, of length 9, which is "words.txt".

You want `new Scanner(new File("words.txt"))`.

Comment: Didn't see that the `PrintWriter` was part of try-with-resource. Deleted the answer. Thanks